# File missing error when running python job in Spark on EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I'm attempting to submit a step to an existing emr cluster:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXXXXXXXX --steps Type=spark,Name=MyApp,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false,--num-executors,5,--executor-cores,5,--executor-memory,5g,file.py,--py-files,support-files.zip],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

However, the step fails with a missing file error?

```
16/08/31 19:01:06 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8032
16/08/31 19:01:07 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 2 NodeManagers
16/08/31 19:01:07 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (11520 MB per container)
16/08/31 19:01:07 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 11520 MB memory including 1047 MB overhead
16/08/31 19:01:07 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
16/08/31 19:01:07 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
16/08/31 19:01:07 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
16/08/31 19:01:07 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
16/08/31 19:01:09 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/tmp/spark-e3f0079d-1c1a-4e68-9e69-2f83368d4405/__spark_libs__7513771565880645694.zip -> hdfs://ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1414534513678_0014/__spark_libs__7513771565880645694.zip
16/08/31 19:01:10 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-2746P63VUU8PI/file.py -> hdfs://ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1414534513678_0014/file.py
16/08/31 19:01:10 INFO Client: Deleting staging directory hdfs://ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1414534513678_0014
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-2746P63VUU8PI/file.py does not exist
```

as far as i can tell, the file was correctly uploaded? any ideas what else might cause this problem?

---

- the file exists where i execute `aws emr add-steps`
- the file appears to exist on at least the master note; i don't have an easy way to confirm since the process attempts to delete it (see log below) upon failure

Comment: Can you check whether `file.py` exists where you execute `aws emr add-steps` and on the nodes?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski updated question with more info. Note that copying the relevant files over to the master node and performing `spark-submit` works just fine